# Can the scalar multiplication's choice change the bases of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an additive group $(V, +)$ and a field $\mathbb{K}$, sometimes there is more than one possible definition for a scalar multiplication $\mathbb{K} \times V \to V$ in order to make $(V,+,\cdot)$ a vector space (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595068/vector-spaces-is-the-scalar-multiplication-unique)). My question is: can the choice of such a scalar multiplication affect the family of bases of the vector space $V$? In other words: if I change only the scalar multiplication (not changing the field $\mathbb{K}$ or the additive group $(V, +)$), can this change transform some $X \subset V$ that is not a basis into a basis, or vice-versa?

Comment: A basis means $V = \sum_j K. b_j$ so you don't need to change of basis if $\{ k.b_j, k \in K\}$ stays the same after changing you definition of $k.b_j$. In particular if $\sigma \in Aut(K)$ letting $k\square b_j=\sigma(k).b_j$ gives $K \square b_j = K.b_j$.

Comment: @reuns If I understood it, you are saying that if $\cdot$ and $\ast$ are scalar multiplications such that $\{k \cdot \vec{v} \mid k \in K, \vec{v} \in V \} = \{k \ast \vec{v} \mid k \in K, \vec{v} \in V \}$, then every basis of $(V, +, \cdot)$ is a basis in $(V, +, \ast)$. But my question is: given any scalar multiplications $\cdot: K \times V \to V$ and $\ast: K \times V \to V$, is it necessarily true that every basis of $(V, +, \cdot)$ is a basis of $(V, +, \ast)$? If it is, why? If it is not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(t)$ the field of rational functions. It is a one-dimensional $K$ vector space and also a countably infinite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, so it is isomorphic to $K^2$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Let $\phi$ be such an isomorphism and let $a(t) * v = \phi^{-1}(a(t) . \phi(v))$ where $.$ is the natural $K$-action on $K$ and $K^2$

Comment: Note for any $K$-vector space $V$ with $K$ a field of characteristic $0$, the group structure on $V$ carries a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure, but nothing more. So in general the answer to your latter question is yes if $K = \mathbb{Q}$ and no otherwise.